# Hide / Show View Controller instead of Add / Remove to Parent

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I have a view controller A. In this View Controller, I have a button and tapping on that button display a View Controller B which has a webview.

I want to hide that webview containing view controller (B) instead of removing it and I want to instantiate this webview once in a lifecycle period.

Basicaly, I want to instantiate a view controller only once and want to hide (not remove) it so that later I can continue with that state of the hidden view controller.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: A view controller isn't visible; it’s views are.  Set the controller's main view hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement was -> From `ViewController A`, If user opens `ViewController B` then `ViewController B` will be displayed which contains `only` a webView.

Once user presses `Save` button on a `ViewController B` then the `ViewController B` will be closed (i.e. that will be removed from view hierarchy) and user will be navigate back to `ViewController A`.

And that time I need to save the `ViewController B`, so that later user can be displayed the loaded WebView, instead of initializing the `ViewController B` again.

**Solution:**
I've solved this requirement by creating a static dictionary of type String:ViewController (used a string as a key). Later when I need to display the loaded `ViewController B` then I can just search in that static dictionary and if found then the loaded ViewController can be displayed to the user.

```
private var viewControllers: [String: UIViewController] = [:]
    
func addViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, for key: String) {
    viewControllers[key] = viewController
}

func getViewController(for key: String) -> UIViewController? {
    viewControllers[key]
}

func deleteViewControllers() {
    viewControllers.removeAll()
}
```

I've used these three function to save access and delete `ViewController B`.